# Select columns of table index

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

Oracle has a query that selects the existing indexes of a table. 
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM user_indexes WHERE table_name = 'CM_WCEL';
```

But I need to recreate the index creation statement. 
How can I get the remaining information like the affected columns, etc?

Comment: To recreate the `create index`  statement it's better to use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()`

Comment: have you checked in `dba_ind_columns` or `user_ind_columns`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That method returns all the ddl right? i need to parse it after and find the index information?

Comment: No you don't need to parse it, the result **is** the "index creation statement"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name somehow, `dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','TABLE_NAME','SCHEMA')` only gave me table creation script and not the indices. Not sure, if I need to pass something else.

Comment: select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','IWCEL2N') from DUAL works!

Comment: @AndréAlves cheers! got it.. was just being stupid there with `get_ddl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the complete DDL for each index, use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()`:

```
select index_name, dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', index_name) as ddl
from user_indexes
where table_name = CM_WCEL';
```

The DDL is returned as a CLOB. Depending on the SQL client you are using you might need some configuration changes to be able to see the complete code. e.g. in SQL*Plus you need something `set long 60000` before you run the select statement.

Answer (score 3):

As per the creation of table, the below tables will have the requested information.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_ind_columns
WHERE table_name = 'CM_WCEL';
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM dba_ind_columns
WHERE table_name = 'CM_WCEL';
```

Answer (score 1):

this should provide needed information:

```
 select index_name, column_name
 from user_ind_columns
 where table_name = 'CM_WCEL';
```