# How to determine the column/columns names that it indexes by the index name in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find out which column/columns the index is specified for in Orcale.
But the request

```
select * from user_indexes where  index_name like 'MY_PK_INDEX_NAME';
```

does not return this information.

How can I find out the names of columns that this index is assigned to?

Comment: Do you mean [`user_ind_columns`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/USER_IND_COLUMNS.html)?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43872487/266304)?

Comment: AlexPoole, thanks!